# dial tcp: lookup auth.ipv6.docker.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host

Tags: docker, sentry

I am self host sentry with https://github.com/getsentry/self-hosted , when run `./install.sh`,raise the error with no such host

```
#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim
#3 ERROR: failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.ipv6.docker.com/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fdebian%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp: lookup auth.ipv6.docker.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM debian:bullseye-slim
   2 |
   3 |     LABEL MAINTAINER="oss@sentry.io"
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: debian:bullseye-slim: failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.ipv6.docker.com/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fdebian%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp: lookup auth.ipv6.docker.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

did not set any proxy

I had disable ipv6 in network setting,but not work.
system with debain 12
`uname` show:
`Linux thyhates 6.1.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.38-4 (2023-08-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

In macOS, when i run `docker run hello-world`,raise the same error:

```bash
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest": Get "https://auth.ipv6.docker.com/token?account=thyhates&scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fhello-world%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dialing auth.ipv6.docker.com:443 with direct connection: resolving host auth.ipv6.docker.com: lookup auth.ipv6.docker.com: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: Are you using Docker in Docker, by any chance?

Comment: @vctls use docker in virtual machine

Comment: There are currently some issues with ipv6 due to Docker globally enabling ipv6 for their registry a few hours ago. Take a look at the suggested fixes in the following Github issue: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/2165

Comment: I tried to summarize what I could gather on that other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76967226/docker-authentification-failed-to-fetch-anonymous-token/76969794
Sorry, I only realized afterwards that you'd asked first 