# Docker Authentification: failed to fetch anonymous token

Tags: docker, gitlab, ipv6, runner

I got the following error inside my gitlab runner:

ERROR: failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.ipv6.docker.com/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fnode%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp [2600:1f18:2148:bc02:4bf0:3a98:55ae:e3d5]:443: connect: cannot assign requested address

see: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/

Is there a way to change auth.ipv6.docker.com with auth.ipv4.docker.com somewhere ?

Comment: Are you using Docker in Docker, by any chance?

Comment: yes, i'm using dind

Comment: Interesting. We're having the same issue with our Docker runners since yesterday. It may match with this change in Docker Registry: they just enabled IPv6 globally a few hours ago.
https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-hub-registry-ipv6-support-now-generally-available/

Comment: There are already more reports of the same error here: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/2165

Comment: In addition to GitHub, Docker is tracking the incident at https://www.dockerstatus.com/pages/incident/533c6539221ae15e3f000031/64e75cde1670c8052e6ffd6d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an [outage](https://www.dockerstatus.com/pages/incident/533c6539221ae15e3f000031/64e75cde1670c8052e6ffd6d) triggered by Docker IPv6 migration. It has been fixed by Docker upstream so [you should no longer see the issue](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/2165#issuecomment-1692070170). If you're still having problems with it, follow up in their [GitHub issue on the IPv6 migration](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/2165).